# Call function from another function with parameters passed from both functions

Tags: javascript

I have this `load-more` listener on a button that calls the functions and it works fine.

```
let moviesPage = 1;
let seriesPage = 1;

document.getElementById('load-more').addEventListener('click', () => {

  if (document.querySelector('#movies.active-link')) {

    moviesPage++;
    getMovies(moviesPage); 

    //getMovies(genreId, moviesPage); 

  } else if (document.querySelector('#series.active-link')) {

    seriesPage++;
    getSeries(seriesPage);

  }

});
```

Now I have another listener on a list of links that calls the following code. It takes the `genreId` from the event parameter to sent as an argument to the api call. Also works fine so far.

```
document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').addEventListener('click', 
getByGenre);

function getByGenre (e) {


    const genreId = e.target.dataset.genre;


    movie.movieGenre(genreId)
        .then(movieGenreRes => {
            ui.printMovieByGenre(movieGenreRes);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

};
```

What I want to do is to call `getByGenre` from the `load-more` listener while passing also the moviesPage argument as you can see on the commented code so it can also be passed to the api call.

What would be the best way to do that? I've looked into .call() and .bind() but I'm not sure if it's the right direction to look at or even how to implement it in this situation.

Comment: Just call it `getByGenre(moviesPage)`.

Comment: @AjAX. Doesn't work. Logs `Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined`. Since I don't pass the genreId I guess.

Comment: Sorry. Now I got it. You want to trigger a `click` on `.dropdown-menu` from `load-more()`. [This article demonstrates how to create and dispatch DOM events.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

*Kludge: Global State*

The simplest, though not the most elegant, way for you to solve this problem right now is by using some global state.

Take a global `selection` object that holds the selected `genreId`. Make sure you declare the object literal *before* using it anywhere.

So, your code might look something like so:

```
var selection = { };

document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').addEventListener('click', 
getByGenre);

function getByGenre (e) {

    const genreId = e.target.dataset.genre;

    selection.genreId = genreId;

    movie.movieGenre(...);

};

...

let moviesPage = 1;
let seriesPage = 1;

document.getElementById('load-more').addEventListener('click', () => {

  if (document.querySelector('#movies.active-link')) {

    ...

    if (selection.genreId !== undefined) {
       getMovies(selection.genreId, moviesPage); 
    }

  } else if (...)) {

    ...

  }

});
```

*Closure*

A more elegant way for you to accomplish this is by using a closure, but for that I have to know your code structure a bit more. For now, global state like the above will work for you.

**Longer Answer**

Your concerns have not been separated. You are mixing up more than one concern in your objects.

For e.g. to load more movies, in your `load-more` listener, you call a function named `getMovies`. However, from within the `.dropdown-menu` listener, you call into a `movie` object's method via the `getByGenre` method.

Ideally, you want to keep your UI concerns (such as selecting elements by using a query selector or reading data from elements) separate from your actual business objects. So, a more extensible model would have been like below:

```
var movies = {
    get: function(howMany) {

        if (howMany === undefined) {
          howMany = defaultNumberOfMoviesToGetPerCall;
        }

        if (movies.genreId !== undefined) {
            // get only those movies of the selected genre
        } else {
          // get all kinds of movies
        }
    },

    genreId : undefined,

    defaultNumberOfMoviesToGetPerCall: 25
};

document.get...('.load-more').addEventListener('whatever', (e) => {
    var moviesArray = movies.get();

    // do UI things with the moviesArray
});


document.get...('.dropdown-menu').addEventListener('whatever', (e) => {
    movies.genreId = e.target.dataset.genreId;

    var moviesArray = movies.get();

    // do UI things with the moviesArray
});
```

Comment: First example doesn't seem to work. I get the value of the `genreId` into the object as a global but the problem is on the second conditional I think. It calls again the `getByGenre` function and as a result I log an error of undefined on the `e.target.dataset.genre`. I will look into closures more closely or think of another way to structure the code. Anyway here the complete code if you're interested in a more detailed view https://github.com/grenos/Popcorn-Style-Online

Comment: You need to learn JavaScript for at least 6 months to a year full-time before you work on that codebase in your git repo, which I am guessing you got from somewhere else. I cannot do your homework. Learn JavaScript.

Comment: Well your guess is wrong but it doesn't really matter does it? Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: The many bad smells in your question and comments suggest that your expertise is not anywhere near in tandem with the expertise of the person who actually wrote the code in your git repo. (1) You do not know how to precisely explain your problem. (2) Your comment to my reply is still just as vague and unhelpful for anyone to be able to help. (3) A close observation of the code in your repo reveals inconsistencies in writing style, so more than one hand wrote it, and you're probably now maintaining it. (4) Your latest comment reveals that you do not even know the basics of HTML5 even. contd...

Comment: Coming back to  your question (and at this point, I have very little motivation to help you further, but I don't know why I am), you don't have a `data-genre` attribute on your `<div class="dropdown-menu text-center" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"></div>`. That is why you get the `e.target.dataset.genre` undefined. Please learn some HTML. And learn some JavaScript. Don't play with production code without learning the basic things. Learn something. That you don't know these basic things is a huge red flag and needs no contest.

Comment: Look inside the `printMovieGenres` function in your `ui.js` (https://github.com/grenos/Popcorn-Style-Online/blob/master/src/js/userscripts/ui.js#L419) and you will find that you have the `data-genre` attribute on an anchor tag with the class name `dropdown-item` and not on its parent `div` with the class name `dropdown-menu`. `output += 
                <a class="dropdown-item" data-genre="${id}" href="#">${name}</a>`

Comment: So, change `document.get...('.dropdown-menu').addEventListener('whatever', (e) => {` to `document.get...('.dropdown-item').addEventListener('whatever', (e) => {`